# Django "on_delete=models.CASCADE" not working in 2.0?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a simple model relationship with on_delete=models.CASCADE.
Here is my code:-

```
class Answer_Options(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Quiz(models.Model):
    q_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    possible_answers = models.ManyToManyField(Answer_Options, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

It is giving me the following error on terminal:-
TypeError: _init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_delete'
Location:- django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1129

Comment: That has never worked (it doesn’t really make sense). Are you sure you didn’t want a `OneToManyField`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the nature of a ManyToMany relationship.

One model should not get deleted on deleting of the related model in ManyToMany relationship.

`on_delete` is only available with the standard `OneToOneField` and `OneToManyField`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple script for Mass replace (NOTE! You must test output data!!!):

```
import os
import fileinput
from termcolor import colored
for dname, dirs, files in os.walk("apps"):
    for fname in files:
        fpath = os.path.join(dname, fname)
        if fname == 'models.py':
            output = []
            print fname
            with open(fpath) as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                for line in lines:

                    if ('ForeignKey' in line) or ('OneToOneField' in line):
                        print colored(line,'yellow')
                        if 'GenericForeignKey' in line: 
                            output.append(line)
                        else:        
                            repl_line = line.rstrip()
                            if repl_line[-1] == ')' and not 'on_delete' in line:
                                if repl_line[-2] == ',':
                                    repl_line = '%s on_delete=models.CASCADE)\n' % repl_line[:-1]
                                elif repl_line[-3] == ',':
                                    '%son_delete=models.CASCADE)\n' % repl_line[:-1]     
                                else:
                                    repl_line = '%s, on_delete=models.CASCADE)\n' % repl_line[:-1]
                                print colored(repl_line,'green')    
                                output.append(repl_line)    
                            else:    
                                output.append(line)
                    else:
                        output.append(line)   


            f.close()
            f = open(fpath,"w")
            f.write(''.join(output))
            f.close()
```